# Google Apps Script with Google Sheets, detect (eventListener) if user switches to different Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

At the moment this is my solution to see if a user switches to a different sheet inside of a Spreadsheet.

frontend.js

```js
poll();

function poll() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(checkTab()).withFailureHandler().checkTabFunction();
  }, 2000);
};

function checkTab(check) {
  check ? openTimeTrigger(true) : toggleTimeTrigger("close");
  poll();
};
```

backend.js

```js
function checkTabFunction() {

  let currentID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  let triggerID = Number(scriptProperties.getProperty('triggerSheet'));

  if(currentID === triggerID){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

This leads to a never ending lifecycle of net changes:
[image]

This cycle crashes also at some point.

What would be the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, in your situation, is this answer useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61864890

Comment: @Tanaike thank you, this does help a lot even though i now have a new problem. I need to call a function from the client-side via Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

The never ending cycle is probably because you're creating multiple `setInterval` triggers:

> google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(checkTab())

`checkTab()` is called every time the server function is called(Not as a success handler) Not only that `checkTab` calls the `poll` function again creating multi-level loops.

1. Send a function and not the result of the function to the success handler

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(checkTab).withFailureHandler().checkTabFunction();
  }, 2000);
};
```

2. Avoid recreating  the setInterval again in the success Handler function:

```
function checkTab(check) {
  check ? openTimeTrigger(true) : toggleTimeTrigger("close");
/*Removed  poll();*/
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but i am looking for a solution where i dont have a never ending loop, but also want a listener if the user switches Sheets.